# Cannot run STM32 L1 Discovery board

Tags: stm32, openocd, stm32ldiscovery, stm32l152

I have fresh STM32 L1 discovery board, and it seems to be broken.
But I am not completely sure.

When connecting board via USB to the Linux machine, board starts 
perfectly fine, and the demo works just as described by vendor.

But I am unable to actually connect to this board.

```
➜ lsusb -s 002:074
Bus 002 Device 074: ID 0483:3748 STMicroelectronics ST-LINK/V2
```

Board seems to be connected, big jumper (CN3) to switch between ST-LINK and DISCOVERY is set to DISCOVERY. But when I try to use st-link utility
I am receiving.

```
➜  stlink git:(master) ./st-flash --reset erase
libusb_handle_events() timeout
[!] send_recv
libusb_submit_transfer(-6)
[!] send_recv
libusb_submit_transfer(-6)
[!] send_recv
libusb_submit_transfer(-6)
[!] send_recv
libusb_submit_transfer(-6)
[!] send_recv
2015-12-25T19:24:57 INFO src/stlink-common.c: Loading device parameters....
libusb_submit_transfer(-6)
[!] send_recv
libusb_submit_transfer(-6)
[!] send_recv
libusb_submit_transfer(-6)
[!] send_recv
2015-12-25T19:24:57 WARN src/stlink-common.c: unknown chip id! 0
fish: Job 1, './st-flash --reset erase' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

Also OpenOCD is unable to talk to the board.

```
openocd -f board/stm32ldiscovery.cfg
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.9.0 (2015-12-25-18:43)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
     http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
adapter speed: 300 kHz
adapter_nsrst_delay: 100
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
none separate
srst_only separate srst_nogate srst_open_drain connect_deassert_srst
Info : Unable to match requested speed 300 kHz, using 240 kHz
Info : Unable to match requested speed 300 kHz, using 240 kHz
Info : clock speed 240 kHz
Error: reset device failed
in procedure 'init' 
in procedure 'ocd_bouncer'
```

The chip on board is STM32L152RCT6. I worked with STM32F0..4 before and had never such problems, but I did not worked with L series before, so I am not sure if this is board problem or I am skipping something important here.

EDIT: Using OpenOCD i found out not expected behaviour. At first run I am receiving error:

```
Error: init mode failed (unable to connect to the target)
```

At second run:

```
Error: reset device failed
```

Then device dissapears from the system, `dmesg` leaves messages:

```
[ 1336.080239] usb 2-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 1336.154250] usb 2-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 1336.329341] usb 2-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 1336.503334] usb 2-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 1336.566330] usb 2-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 1336.741385] usb 2-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 1336.915427] usb 2-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 1337.317517] usb 2-1.1: device not accepting address 4, error -32
[ 1337.390532] usb 2-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 1337.792623] usb 2-1.1: device not accepting address 4, error -32
[ 1337.793110] usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 4
[ 1337.855642] usb 2-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[ 1337.918651] usb 2-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 1338.093691] usb 2-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 1338.267730] usb 2-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[ 1338.330727] usb 2-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 1338.505783] usb 2-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 1338.679823] usb 2-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[ 1339.081921] usb 2-1.1: device not accepting address 7, error -32
[ 1339.154935] usb 2-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[ 1339.557024] usb 2-1.1: device not accepting address 8, error -32
[ 1339.557168] usb 2-1-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
```

I think there might be a problem with adapter speed, but I am not sure for now.

EDIT2: I tried with Windows ST Link Utility and I am not able to connect to the board, board causing "Detection Error" or "Connection Error", software suggests changing SWD frequency or mode. I tired with literally every combination but none works.

EDIT3: If this helps somebody, board was sent back, I have got information that it is actually broken and I have got new one. New one works flawlessly as expected.

Comment: probably you have broken ST-Link programmer device

Comment: try disconnecting the jumpers that connect the stlink portion to the mcu under test, see if that allows you to at least connect to the stlink.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried this before, no changes in software response, the same output.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes I work with the same L1 Discovery board on GNU/Linux. Both [texane/stlink](https://github.com/texane/stlink) and OpenOCD detect it flawlessly without any modification. You can see the outputs:

```
$ st-util 
2016-01-08T21:55:59 INFO src/stlink-common.c: Loading device parameters....
2016-01-08T21:55:59 INFO src/stlink-common.c: Device connected is: L1 Med-density device, id 0x10186416
2016-01-08T21:55:59 INFO src/stlink-common.c: SRAM size: 0x4000 bytes (16 KiB), Flash: 0x20000 bytes (128 KiB) in pages of 256 bytes
2016-01-08T21:55:59 INFO gdbserver/gdb-server.c: Chip ID is 00000416, Core ID is  2ba01477.
2016-01-08T21:55:59 INFO gdbserver/gdb-server.c: Target voltage is 2917 mV.
2016-01-08T21:55:59 INFO gdbserver/gdb-server.c: Listening at *:4242...
$ openocd -f board/stm32ldiscovery.cfg 
GNU ARM Eclipse 64-bits Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0-dev-00141-g09aeb96-dirty (2015-10-28-11:56)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
adapter speed: 300 kHz
adapter_nsrst_delay: 100
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The    results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
none separate
srst_only separate srst_nogate srst_open_drain connect_deassert_srst
Info : Unable to match requested speed 300 kHz, using 240 kHz
Info : Unable to match requested speed 300 kHz, using 240 kHz
Info : clock speed 240 kHz
Info : STLINK v2 JTAG v25 API v2 SWIM v0 VID 0x0483 PID 0x3748
Info : using stlink api v2
Info : Target voltage: 2.913980
Info : stm32l1.cpu: hardware has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
```

Maybe your board is really broken but before recycle it I suggest you two different trials. (a) I think after your question you have another ST (as you mentioned STM32F0..4) board perhaps with ST-LINK adaptor. You can use it as an external ST-LINK (follow eg. [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/182763/how-to-use-an-external-st-link-v2-with-the-stm32f4-discovery-board)). (b) Try to upgrade your embedded ST-LINK firmware with the [STSW-LINK005](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF258194) which java version works also in GNU/Linux environment. The board performs well for me both before and after upgrade.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer and provided output. I was not sure before if the OpenOCD should work out-of-box or not. I have even dedicated ARM jtag (FT2232 based oocdlink) and the MPU on board seems to work, so unfortunately on-board st-link is broken somehow. I wonder if I am able to find a malfunction without oscilloscope. About upgrading firmware, I have tried this before, upgrading software shows that upgade goes flawlessly, but device does not change behaviour.